# How does migration of a question work?

Tags: support

Just out of curiosity, today I saw the privileges of different users, but found nobody who has the privilege to migrate a question. Moderators can only see the recently migrated question in moderator tool. But how is then migration of a question take place? Flagging a question to be migrated is possible for any user. Who is then there is to decide the question should be migrated or not and do this or take necessary step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any user with flag rights can flag a question for migration.

Moderators can have the final say and actually perform the migration and see all flags for migrations.

Typically the migration process is us asking other site mods if the question is proper for them to ensure the question would not be just closed for being off-topic.